# Java- Spring: should we handle null on a list in a request-Object?

Tags: java, spring, system-design

should we handle null on a list in a request-Object.

I am using Spring (java) to accept `the request to save a new Student`.

Eg :

```
@Data
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    
    private List<String> subjects;

}
```

**My question**  is more of a contract between front-end and backend.

**What I need is** : a logical-explanation/opinion on should we allow NULLs on `student.subjects` OR not ?

--

**Extra :**

i have referenced multiple opinions on the internet.

The one that makes the most sense is : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/217411

Comment: You seem confused. Whether null should be allowed or not for `subjects` depends on your use case. If it is mandatory, don't allow null else allow null.

Comment: This seems mostly like an opinion based question. Note that you could always attribute a default value to `subjects` by doing `private List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<>();` with a builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your project requirements, but from a clean code standpoint, there are two key principles that are relevant in this context.

1. **Do not return NULL**

- If you are tempted to return `NULL`, you should consider throwing an exception or returning a `special case` (a special case is a specific situation or condition that deviates from the normal flow of execution or behavior)
  Special case example:

```
List<Employee> employees = getEmployees();
if (employees != null) { // we check for null because getEmployees can return null
   for(Employee e : employees) {
      totalPay += e.getPay();
   }
}
```

```
// If we change getEmployees so that it returns an empty list,
// we can clean up the code

List<Employee> employees = getEmployees();
for(Employee e : employees) {
   totalPay += e.getPay();
}
```

2. **Do not pass NULL**

- you should avoid passing `NULL` in your code whenever possible, unless you
  are working with an API which expects you to pass `NULL`
- if someone passes `NULL`, we could not handle it better than throwing a `Runtime Exception` - so we'll still have a runtime error

These two points help us understand that we should consider simplifying the client code and reducing clutter in the business logic.

Therefore, from a clean code perspective, we should **avoid** dealing with `NULL` in our code whenever possible.

Reference: "Clean Code. A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship"